# Issue with translating cosine equation into a matlab code

Tags: matlab, math, trigonometry, angle

I'm writing MATLAB code that requires implementing some mathematical equations.  The equation that I'm trying to write into a Matlab code is:

```
Result = X cosTheta - Y sin Theta
```

where

```
X = (x1-x2)  
Y = (y1-y2)
```

My interpretation is:

```
Result = (X*cos(Theta)) - (Y*sin(Theta))
```

Is it correct to represent `X cos Theta` by multiplying `X` to `cos(Theta)`, or am I required to write different code?

Comment: I would say: everything ok. At least this is how I would interpret your instruction `Result = X cosTheta - Y sin Theta`. However, you should know what it is supposed to mean... notes: if `X`, `Y` and `Theta` are vectors you might want to use `.*` instead of `*`; and you can discard some of your braces.

Comment: Looks fine to me. The best way to figure out if the representation is correct, is to run the code and see if the output is what you want.

Comment: and don't forget that in Matlab angles should be expressed in radian. So if your input angles are in degree you have to convert them before calling `cos` or `sin`

Comment: Or use `cosd` and `sind`, which are provided for convenience (but you should get into the habit of using radians).